# Heroku production app suddenly stopped working and serves "syntax error" though there is none

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, version-control

My production app has suddenly and mysteriously stopped working. Works fine locally.

**Heroku logs show me this error:**

```
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require':
 /app/app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:84: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting $end (SyntaxError)
```

I have cleaned up whitespace in the controller but it doesn't seem to fix anything. There is not a floating `end` anywhere either.
no migrations pending either

**I suspect this is a gem dependency issue**
But don't actually know. I'm not the greatest with version control.
I'm picking up work on this project after about a 10 week break for school. So maybe something has broken over that time period with gem updates and it only just manifested itself in total production server failure today.

full logs:

```
Exiting
2013-11-30T03:12:56.528872+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
2013-11-30T03:12:56.528872+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': /app/app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:84: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting $end (SyntaxError)
2013-11-30T03:12:56.528872+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
2013-11-30T03:12:56.528872+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2013-11-30T03:12:56.528872+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:359:in `require_or_load'
2013-11-30T03:12:56.529118+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:313:in `depend_on'
2013-11-30T03:12:56.529118+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/engine.rb:439:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
2013-11-30T03:12:56.529118+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `each'
2013-11-30T03:12:56.529118+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `block in eager_load!'
2013-11-30T03:12:56.529118+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `each'
2013-11-30T03:12:56.529118+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `require_dependency'
2013-11-30T03:12:56.529118+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2013-11-30T03:12:56.529118+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2013-11-30T03:12:56.529324+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2013-11-30T03:12:56.529324+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
2013-11-30T03:12:56.529118+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `eager_load!'
2013-11-30T03:12:56.529324+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
2013-11-30T03:12:56.529324+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2013-11-30T03:12:56.529118+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:53:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2013-11-30T03:12:56.529324+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2013-11-30T03:12:56.529324+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
2013-11-30T03:12:56.529812+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2013-11-30T03:12:56.529324+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
2013-11-30T03:12:56.529812+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
2013-11-30T03:12:56.529812+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `new'
2013-11-30T03:12:56.529324+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/environment.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
2013-11-30T03:12:56.529812+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
2013-11-30T03:12:56.529812+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:304:in `wrapped_app'
2013-11-30T03:12:56.529812+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
2013-11-30T03:12:56.529968+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:254:in `start'
2013-11-30T03:12:56.529968+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
2013-11-30T03:12:56.529968+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
2013-11-30T03:12:56.529968+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
2013-11-30T03:12:56.529324+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
2013-11-30T03:12:56.529812+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2013-11-30T03:12:56.529812+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2013-11-30T03:12:56.529968+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
2013-11-30T03:12:56.529968+00:00 app[web.1]:    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
2013-11-30T03:12:56.529968+00:00 app[web.1]:    from script/rails:6:in `require'
2013-11-30T03:12:56.529812+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
2013-11-30T03:12:56.529812+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2013-11-30T03:12:56.529324+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2013-11-30T03:12:57.855534+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2013-11-30T03:12:57.866879+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-11-30T03:13:05.403562+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=peopleandstuff.com fwd="24.128.163.195" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-11-30T03:13:08.057496+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=peopleandstuff.com fwd="24.128.163.195" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-11-30T03:13:10.257229+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=peopleandstuff.com fwd="24.128.163.195" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-11-30T03:16:22.969850+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=peopleandstuff.com fwd="24.128.163.195" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-11-30T03:16:23.473382+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=peopleandstuff.com fwd="24.128.163.195" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-11-30T03:16:23.530070+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=peopleandstuff.com fwd="24.128.163.195" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-11-30T03:16:25.601918+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=peopleandstuff.com fwd="24.128.163.195" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

**Sessions Controller:**
gist: [gist.github.com/anonymous/7715681](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7715681)

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  # skip_before_filter :require_login
  # skip_before_filter :authorize

  #sessions implemented using Clearance gem
  def new
  end
  def create_facebook
    # user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
    # session[:user_id] = user.id
    # redirect_to root_url
      auth_hash = request.env["omniauth.auth"]

      authentication = Authentication.find_by_provider_and_uid(auth_hash["provider"], auth_hash["uid"]) || Authentication.create_with_omniauth(auth_hash)
      if authentication.user
        user = authentication.user 
        authentication.update_token(auth_hash)
        @next = root_url
        @notice = "Signed in!"
      else
        user = User.create_with_auth_and_hash(authentication,auth_hash)
        @next = edit_user_path(user)   
        @notice = "User created - confirm or edit details..."
      end
      sign_in(user)
      redirect_to @next, :notice => @notice
    end
  end
  def create
    @user = User.authenticate(params[:session][:email],
                             params[:session][:password])
    if @user.nil?
      #create an error message and rerender signin form
      flash.now[:error] = "Invalid email/password"
      @title = "Sign in"
      render 'new'
    else
      #sign the user in and redirect to the user's show page.
      sign_in @user
      redirect_back_or @user, nil
    end
  end

  def destroy
    sign_out
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  private
    def redirect_back_or(default, notice)
      flash[:notice] = notice
      if session[:followed_tag]
        @tag = Tag.find(session[:followed_tag])
        unless current_user.followed_tags.include?(@group)
          current_user.follow!(@tag)
        end
        session.delete(:followed_tag)
      end
      if session[:joined_group]
        @group = Group.find(session[:joined_group])
        unless current_user.groups_as_member.include?(@group)
          current_user.join!(@group)
        end
        session.delete(:joined_group)
      end
      if session[:return_to]
        redirect_to session[:return_to]
        session.delete(:return_to)
      else
        redirect_to default
      end
    end
    def store_location
      session[:return_to] = request.fullpath
    end
end
```

Thanks guys for any help

Comment: Could you post your whole sessions controller here?

Comment: added sessions controller

Comment: gist: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7715681

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an extra `end` at the end of your `create_facebook` action. If you look at the indentation you will see that you have an `end` that doesn't line up with the start of a block:

```
def create_facebook
  # user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
  # session[:user_id] = user.id
  # redirect_to root_url
    auth_hash = request.env["omniauth.auth"]

    authentication = Authentication.find_by_provider_and_uid(auth_hash["provider"], auth_hash["uid"]) || Authentication.create_with_omniauth(auth_hash)
    if authentication.user
      user = authentication.user 
      authentication.update_token(auth_hash)
      @next = root_url
      @notice = "Signed in!"
    else
      user = User.create_with_auth_and_hash(authentication,auth_hash)
      @next = edit_user_path(user)   
      @notice = "User created - confirm or edit details..."
    end
    sign_in(user)
    redirect_to @next, :notice => @notice
  end # <--- **** This one ****
end
```

Comment: thanks- clearly I can't count. enjoy the rest of your weekend